# Getting null pointer exception in shared preferences android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

My code is something like this

// To save my form data

```
private final OnClickListener mFinishListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();

        editor.putString("txtName",mName.getText().toString());

        servState = 1;
        editor.putInt("AppState", servState);
        editor.commit();

        }
```

// To Retrieve my form data

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
        int restoreServState = prefs.getInt("AppState", 0);


        if(restoreServState == 0){
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFinish);
            button.setOnClickListener(mFinishListener);
        }
        else {

            setContentView(R.layout.pwd);
            int selectionStart = prefs.getInt("selection-start", -1);
            int selectionEnd = prefs.getInt("selection-end", -1);
            if (selectionStart != -1 && selectionEnd != -1) {
                //mSaved.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
            }
        }

    }
```

I get NullPointerException at the point of saving the data in the OnClick event in the above code. The exact line I got problem is

```
    editor.putString("txtName",mName.getText().toString());
```

Please suggest what is the wrong here? Do I need to change anything in the manifest file to use shared preferences?

Comment: There are three different things that might be null -- you need to find out what it is with a little debugging. They are `editor`, `mName`, and `mName.getText()`. Find out which one is null, and let us know.

Comment: mName is not null i checked  , i put a statement like if(editor != null) and it still throw the same and i dint put the textbox empty so it can't be null. any other idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may have two problem for getting this error

Actually when Activity starts it call **onCreate()** first

**onResume()** is called after activity is created so may be your control may not getting the resource

```
1)so had setContentView(R.layout.main) in onCreate?
2)had you initialize EditText mName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.label);?
```

check this things, may works

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aDCxvg7R - I put my code here. I know very little java. Please help.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8zZ1kmE4 check now, actually if you setContent(main) then mPwd will null, if you setContent(pwd) then mName and other will null thats the prob, you have to create your own logic

Comment: i checked the code. It solved the problem. Thanks a lot to you. I saw in your code you commented some code. Can I know what was the problem and what did you fixed? so that i can learn and in future i will not face the same problem?